# How do ants transport water?

Tags: ant

All living things need water to survive. Worker ants can drink directly from the source. But a queen ant would need help from the colony to get its daily supply of food and water. I have seen ants carrying tiny bits of food, but I have not really seen them carrying water. Do they use their hands like how they carry food? Do they use a receptacle like us humans? Or are there some other innovative ways?

Comment: Ants are able to roll water droplets because of how small they themselves are in comparison. It seems odd but that's because different rules apply to the smaller creatures. For instance, a mouse falling from a skyscraper would be stunned, but otherwise uninjured. We, however, would break every bone in our body.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The worker ants give water to the other ants in the nest. Also, they get most of their hydration out of the food anyway.
[Here](http://blog.wildaboutants.com/2010/07/20/do-ants-drink-water/) is a blogpost with some references and nice humour about it.

Comment: The key word is [trophallaxis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trophallaxis).

Comment: Thank you. I love drinking water. so therefore I hate ants.